# Exclude one .html file from codelyzer linting

Tags: tslint, codelyzer

While working on ngx-bootstrap, I have extracted part of datepicker logic
to separate class, and not codelyzer shows a lot of issues like:

`The property "viewMode" that you're trying to access does not exist in the class declaration.`

Such exclude of file doesn't work:

```
tslint \"src/**/*.ts\" -c tslint.json --type-check -p src/tsconfig.spec.json  -e \"**/bs-datepicker-view.html\"

```

Thanks in advance

Comment: is there a workaround for this?